# Computing x and y distances between two raster maps using GRASS GIS?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, distance

I am working with a maximum water elevation raster in which, similarly to using r.grow.distance, I am trying to extract the distance from the each null cell to the nearest water elevation cell. However I need both the x and y distances, which are not provided by r.grow.distance. I looked into the source code for this function and found that the x and y distances are calculated within the code but r.grow.distance can only provide results in euclidean, squared, maximum, manhattan, or geodesic formats. Is there an easy way to extract these x and y distance values? If so, I am working on a real-time storm surge model so it would be ideal to be able to calculate these values in as little time as possible. I also looked into r.distance but this does not seem like an option that would work for me.[image: Sample water elevation raster]

Comment: Please edit your original question with additional info from comment and remove comment.

Comment: So you have a region that is partly covered by water, and all the rest are pixels with NULL?  And you want the distance from all NULL pixels to the water, but split into X-Y components? Perhaps an image would make the question clearer.

Comment: Micha, that is correct. I am essentially trying to pull distance values from r.grow.distance as x and y components. I have added an image of the sample water elevation raster I have been working with. This raster represents the maximum water levels achieved throughout the duration of Hurricane Florence within a small area of the eastern coast of the United States.

Comment: @Micha Sorry, I just realized I did not properly use the @ in my previous comment (I'm new to this). If you are interested in seeing how I was able to resolve this issue, I have posted an answer to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use r.mapcalc to create a raster for all of the x and y values of the original maximum elevation raster. For example:

```
if(maxElevationRast,x(),null())
```

Then I used r.grow.distance to extrapolate the x and y values, covering all null cells. Finally, I used r.mapcalc and simply found the difference between the x() and y() moving-window values and the values extrapolated using r.grow.distance.

This gave me the x and y components of the euclidean distances between each null cell and its closest non-null cell.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for posting the solution.